# How to change background color of Bootstrap Navbar Toggler Icon when it's active when using other frameworks like Materialize?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar, materialize

I am working on a project which requires both Bootstrap & Materialize frameworks. 
I have this navbar toggle which is normal when not in active state.

[image]

But when it goes into active state and has a background fill with the default colors of Materialize CSS.

[image]

I am trying to set the background color to transparent but it doesn't. This is the CSS which I tried.

```
.navbar-toggler-icon{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon :active{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

This is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/arnab4srk/pen/yLYmBeO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an `id`in the `div` that has all the content of the`navbar`.

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg sticky-top w-100" >
            <div id="color" class="container p-2">
                <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-white mx-5 d-none d-sm-block" href="#">ReEvent</a>
                <button  class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span  class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </div>
  </div>
    </body>
```

When I change the color in an `id` if the `id` is on the `div` everything that is inside the `div` will be change together. So I put it just for the `button` receive the changes.

But, I don't know why, the button keeps with the "bug" if you put the `:focus` just on it, so i've put the `:focus` on everything and after this I've removed the `:focus` of the `a` using one specific bg for him.

```css
body{
  background-color: #222;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
#color button :hover, #color :focus, #color button :active{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#color a :focus {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: [my codepen link](https://codepen.io/luigiMinardi/pen/ExVqKNv)